# New observation in linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study

This is a problem from Srivastava and it's prob. simple but I miss the whole point here.

Let's see:

We have $\:k\in \mathbb N\:$ observations $\:(u_1,z_1),...,(u_k,z_k).\:$ The $\:LSE\:$ estimated from these values and from the regression model $\:\mathbf z=\beta\mathbf u+\epsilon\:\:\:$ is $\:\:\:\hat\beta=\sum_{1\leqslant j\leqslant k}u_jz_j/\sum_{1\leqslant j\leqslant k}u_j^2.$

Now suppose a new observation $\:(u_{\mathfrak b},z_\mathfrak b)\:$ becomes available. Then what happens when this new observation lies on the regression line built from the $\:k\:$ observations?

$\text{Question}:\:$

If indeed the new observation lies on the regression line, is the new $\:\hat \beta\:$ with the additional observation the same as the original one? Basically, what's the ultimate difference between additional observations lying or not on the regression line?

Any input is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Think about what it means mathematically for a point to lie on the regression line. The answer will become obvious.

Comment: You need the self-study tag.

Comment: Note that if the point falls on the line the slope can't change for the new fitted line.  So the estimate of $\beta$ remains the same. But think about what happens to the mean square error.

Comment: With a tiny bit of (easy) algebra you can compare the new value of $\hat\beta$ to the old one.  Translate the fact that the new observation lies on the old regression line into the equation $z_{\mathfrak b} = \hat\beta u_{\mathfrak b}$ and go from there.  After comparing the betas, you should then compare the estimates of the variance of $\epsilon$, because those are important and they will change.